# Rails named route for non-id parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am using a non-id parameter in one of my routes like so:

```
get 'users/:attribute' => 'users#special_action', :as => named_route
```

I like the named route thingy and I hoped I can just do:

```
named_route_url(@user)
```

To get a url, where the `:attribute` part gets replaced by `user.attribute`.

To my surprise, routing used what `User.to_param` provides.

While I can understand that this is a convention, I would like to know if there is a way to say I want to specificaly use attribute `x` in my route.

(Example of scenatio, where that might be of benefit is if I want to rename the attribute, but keep the route, I can just rename it in the route.)

Comment: At the moment you are overriding user_path(@user). Is that what you want? If not you can do this: `resources :users { member :special_action }.` If you dont want user.to_param you can access this named route: named_route_url(@user.attribute)

Comment: `named_route_url(@user.attribute)` is exactly what I am trying to avoid, if I change the attribute used to constructed the url, then I need to go through all the places that mention `@user.attribute` and change it.

Comment: You can redefine `named_route_url` in helpers to use `attribute` instead of `to_param`.